# foreach: how to repeat one whole table cell

Tags: knockout.js

How do I repeat a table cell in knockout? The code I have is only repeating the cell contents and not the whole cell.

```
<table class="table table-condensed" >
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: permissableGrouping.permissables, as: 'permissableAccess'}">

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label data-bind="text: permissableAccess.permissable.permissableName()"></label>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td data-bind="foreach: { data: permissableAccess.accessTypes, as: 'accessType' }">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: accessType.hasAccess" />
                            <span data-bind="text: accessType"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td><input type="hidden" data-bind="console: $root" />
                    <input type="button" data-bind="click: $root.dataModel.removePermissable.bind(permissableAccess.permissable)" value="Remove" class="btn btn-default" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the foreach into a comment element:

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: permissableAccess.accessTypes, as: 'accessType' } -->
<td>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: accessType.hasAccess" />
            <span data-bind="text: accessType"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</td>
<!-- /ko -->
```

See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html, note 4

Edit: Of course, you'll want to be sure each row has the same number of accessType elements, or you're going to have some alignment issues. If the count is dynamic, you'd want to know the max number of accessTypes across all the rows (use a computed) and then pad out each loop with some blank cells to make sure the remove control is always in the same column.